# Subject + having (grammar)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I have found the sentence which uses a structure following below:
S + having + O
The sentence is like this :
A name having some properties

In here, I am confuse, does the sentence refer to simple or continuous verb?

Comment: This isn't a sentence, it's a phrase or fragment.

Comment: That is not a sentence -- it is just a noun phrase,  "having some properties" is a reduced relative clause modifying the noun "name".

Comment: "John, having the gun, made sure no-one left the room." Is this what you are looking at?

Comment: @Cargill yes something likes that

Answer (score 1):

There's two different constructs that match what you're talking about.

1. A *present participle* giving more information about something that's happened, as in the comment example: "John, having the gun, ensured that nobody left the room." This describes John by mentioning that he has the gun.
2. A *gerund*, treating an action as a noun. An example would be "John having a gun made the situation ten times more explosive." Here, the phrase is being used to mean "The fact that John had a gun." and that implicit fact is the subject of the verb *made*.

Useful further reading on these two:
http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm